# Some vertices are hidden in edit mode (not using H)

Tags: animation, mesh

Some vertices are missing in edit mode as you can see in the yellow circles on the image. I did not press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them. Why are they hidden?

[image: Hidden vertices]

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If so, please consider [accepting](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) it.

Answer (score 10):

This is because you have a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. They aren't really missing, it is just the surfaces being smoothed over those vertices, hiding them. You can either disable the modifier in edit mode:

[image: Disable In Edit Mode]

Or you can toggle *Limit Selection to Visible*:

[image: Limit Selection to Visible]

Here is an example:
[image: Hidden vertices example]

Comment: Or you can try the button to the right of Novice's first one: it displays your lines as surface fitting curves instead of a cage. Personally I findthat it only makes a significant difference when working with a rather sparse mesh; for something as dense as that face it will probably look/act the same almost everywhere .