# Cup's inside vertices slipping through

Tags: vertices

My cup object's inside vertices is slipping through like this [image]
[image]

I already have recalculate normal, check if there is overlapping vertices or not, and  when i zoom in, the image's vertices just like in above picture but when i zoom out, it is fine, there is no vertices slipping like in the picture. I even use merge tool, but there is no by distance function in the tool unlike in the blender 2.8 version when you get one to merge the vertices.

How to fix this mess?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249719/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/107798/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220728/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28507/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/227689/

Comment: @vklidu Thanks, i didn't know it is because of display of modifier, i thought i had double vertices or overlapping faces or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with your vertices, it's just that you've assigned a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your object, it makes the surface rounder, which may hide the vertices:

[image]

Comment: Just like in vklidu's comment , i forgot to turn on cage option in subsurf modifier, which cause the vertices look like slipping... anyway thank you for your help

Comment: sure, but you need to keep in minde that the On Cage will visually move the vertices

Comment: What do you mean visually move the vertices? Does it make my vertices looks rotated or something depend on which degree you look on it?

Comment: no I mean they will be displayed at the position where they will be if you decide to apply the modifier, not their current position

Comment: Do you mean the origin? Cause when i move the object then i go to edit mode, after that i go back into object mode, then the object's origin still left to where i move my object earlier

Comment: no I mean if you activate the On Cage option you won't see the vertices where they actually are, they will be displayed where they would be if you applied the modifier, so it may be a bit deceiptive when you work on your topology. Another way to see the vertices is to enable the transparency (Alt Z)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135758/discussion-between-earvin-williams-and-moonboots).